# Using the property of a PropType shape as the prop type for another component

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Is it possible to use a property of a PropType shape as the prop type for another component?

E.g.

```
function App({ data}) {
    return(
        <div>
            <Item item={data.item} />
        </div>
    )
}

const appPropTypes = PropTypes.shape({
    foo: PropTYpes.string.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
});

App.propTypes = {
    data: appPropTypes;
};

function Item({ item }) {
     return <div>{item}</div>
}

Item.propTypes = {
    item: , // How can I refer to appPropTypes.item here?
}
```

Obviously the example above is very simple.

But in my actual use case, `item` is much more complex and I'd like to avoid having to have duplicate code in `appPropTypes` and `itemPropTypes`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about accessing a particular PropType, since I believe they give you a function. So, instead of accessing the `item` property from PropTypes, you could probably just save item into it's own const and reuse it as necessary. Something like this:

```js
const itemPropTypes = PropTypes.string.isRequired

const appPropTypes = PropTypes.shape({
    foo: PropTYpes.string.isRequired,
    item: itemPropTypes,
});

App.propTypes = {
    data: appPropTypes;
};
...

Item.propTypes = {
    item: itemPropTypes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `appPropTypes.item` if you move the call to `PropTypes.shape` to the where the data field is defined.

As here in this code snippet:

```js
function App({ data }) {
  return(
      <div>
          <Item item={data.item} />
      </div>
  )
}

const appPropTypes = {  // PropTypes.shape moved below
  foo: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

App.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape(appPropTypes), // PropTypes.shape moved here
};

function Item({ item }) {
   return <div>{item}</div>
}

Item.propTypes = {
  item: appPropTypes.item, // appPropTypes.item here
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App data={{foo:"bar", item:"myItem"}} />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6/prop-types.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```